# React Native : force flexbox direction

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, flexbox, direction

Flexbox general question here,

I know `FlexDirection` is based on the device's default direction settings.

I was just wondering if there's a way to force the Flexbox direction as `flexDirection: 'row'` for example, to be LTR for all devices?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

React does not provide anything to override default style. If you want to achieve that you’ll have to create a custom view and use that instead.

```
// @Component/View.js

import { View } from "react-native";

export default ({ style, ...props }) => <View {...props} style = {{ flexDirection: 'row', ...style }} />
```